# Routing in Django

Tags: python, django, routes

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import page1

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('page1/', page1.hello, name='page1'),
]
```

page1.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
   text = """<h1>welcome to my app !</h1>"""
   return HttpResponse(text)
```

Pretty basic. The page1.py lies in the same directory as urls.py. The examples i found online, use a second urls.py file and an some includes command... do i have a typo or do i need more than that two files?

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: That it doesn't work. So do i need the third file? Are there always two urls.py files involved?

Comment: But what you've written looks fine. You'll have to be more specific about what doesn't work.

Comment: @Strella You need at-least one app to run a custom template. The second urls.py file is the one in the app created using. Refer this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: add error log for better understanding

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mydjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
page1/ [name='page1']
The empty path didn’t match any of these.